# Copy-Paste non-contiguous ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in Excel. I want to copy the header and some data from the middle of sheet to Powerpoint. I know that you can't copy a selection of non-adjacent cells in Excel, but I was under the impression it would work with VBA.

My try:

```
With Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)
    Set rng = Union(.Range("B2:K3"), .Range("B45:K85"))
End With
```

I can select "rng", but I can't paste it anywhere because I get the error message that you can't paste non-adjacent cells.

I've also tried this, but it resulted in the whole table (B2:K85) getting copied:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng1 = .Range("B2:K3")
        Set rng2 = .Range("B45:K85")
        Set NewRng = .Range(rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address)
End With
```

I've googled this question and tried various things, but either I misunderstood what is possible with VBA or I'm making a mistake (over and over again).

So do I have to alter my code or do I have to work around it? My alternative solution would be to copy-paste each of the two ranges, put them underneath each other and then copy the whole, now contiguous range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Areas` property of the `Range` object to get the unionized ranges. Code like the below will loop through each of the sub-ranges, copy them, and paste them elsewhere. Try and adapt to your needs, and write back if you need some help.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim destination As Range


    Set rng = Union(Range("A1:B3"), Range("D1:E2"))
    Set destination = Range("H1")


    For Each r In rng.Areas
        r.Copy destination
        Set destination = destination.Offset(, 3)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer @user3561813! OP, keep in mind that copying a cell is longer than just setting the value of the destination cell to the source value (if the formatting is not important for you). At this very small scale, I don't think it would really matter, but it's always something to consider.

Comment: @CharlesPL This is a good point. There can be a large performance penalty on larger data sets.

Comment: That looks pretty good, thanks a lot! 

Follow up question: I have another sheet with which I would basically do the same, but I'd copy the data to PowerPoint. I would have to think about to get those on the same sheet, but that should work; however, with your method there's no way around the fact that those two areas are two different images in PowerPoint, right? So they have to be moved separately.

Comment: @Alex I'm not too familiar with the interface to PowerPoint. One option that I can think of is to copy the values into a contiguous range on a temporary worksheet. From there, you can select the entire "joined" range as one range for passing into PowerPoint.

Comment: @user3561813 Yeah, that would've been my solution, too. Since it's not a big dataset, it should't be a problem. Thanks again for the help!