# Copy non-contiguous selection from workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I copy data from workbook to another workbook ,copying of `single contiguous selection` works without problem. 
But, If I copied two selections (using CTRL) , even adjacent , nothing copied to the destination workbook (with no error raised). 
How to adapt the below code to make it Copy non-contiguous selection from workbook to another? 
In advance, grateful for useful answer and comments.

```
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook    'Source Workbook
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.ActiveSheet.Range(Selection.Address)
 
    Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = Workbooks.Add  'Destination Workbook
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
 
    srg.Copy drg
    srg.Copy
    drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
 
    Dim r As Range
      For Each r In drg.Rows
        r.WrapText = True
         If r.RowHeight < 40 Then r.RowHeight = 40  'This line works
           Next r
```

Comment: You must have an on error somewhere as that will raise an error.

Comment: @SJR ,no error raised , but no values pasted on destination workbook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690218/copy-paste-non-contiguous-ranges

Comment: Maybe try to put your `srg.Copy`  `drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths` line first, then put the  `srg.Copy drg`. But the selection must be rows within the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer refers to @karma
Just I need to copy columns width **then** copy values after it.

```
srg.Copy
drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
srg.Copy drg
```